# CSS 3 Gradient n pixels from bottom - Webkit/Safari

Tags: webkit, css, linear-gradients

Is there a way to creat a gradient with a stop *n* pixels from the bottom edge of the element?

For example with Moz/Firefox it would look like:

`-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #f00 2%, #d00 31px)`

It should also be noted that this gradient has a companion gradient to do the same thing to the very top of the box. So really the css looks like this for FF and i need to reproduce for webkit:

```
background-image:
      -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgba(255,0,0,0.75) 2%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 31px), 
      -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , rgba(255,0,0,0.75) 2%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 31px);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that with the current webkit syntax. Good news though! There will be a new -webkit-linear-gradient property (just announced on the webkit blog) that basically matches the -moz syntax and will allow you to do this. This syntax should become the definitive CSS3 syntax, so you'll be able to drop the -webkit and -moz entirely at some point. (The old -webkit-gradient property will continue to work indefinitely, but is not favored going forward.)

Comment: Actually i saw that bug report and reviewed the patch from this month... i was just hoping maybe there was something i was missing from the current syntax. Also for anyone else whos interested the new syntax is implemented in v528+ (Nightly Build).

Answer (score 5):

You could use `-webkit-background-size` to size the gradient in pixels and `background-position` to place it at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure what you were after but I manage to stop a gradient in px by using this -

```
background-size:100% 31px; background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, center bottom , #f00 2%, #d00 31px)
```

I hope that [this site](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css3_linear_gradients/) helps you more.

Comment: The problem is `color-stop` only takes percentages (or decimal notation of a precentage), not a definitive value. Meanwhile, the `point` doesnt to seem to figure in the stop position, only the direction - ie. all px definition are taken from the top of the box. I cant calculate a percentage because the gradient should not be proportianl it should always stop exactly 31px from the bottom of the box whether the box is 10px tall or 1000px tall. I can use an image, but im trying to keep the css as consitent as possible.