# CSS gradient at pixel location (not %)

Tags: css, linear-gradients

How can I create a programmatic horizontal gradient that starts at a prescribed location (in pixles on the x-axis)?

Here's the issue- I've got an image set as `background-image` - ideally, what I'd like to do is declare a CSS gradient that starts close to the edge of the image (~1800 pixels) and fades gracefully to full black.

So far, the best solution I have is to have two div elements- one with the photo background and the other with a 1px tall gradient image repeated along the y-axis with a `background-position` that starts at 1780px.

This works, but I really want to get away from the 1px image trick. Any ideas?

```
<div id="photobg">
 <div id="gradientbg">
 </div>
</div>

#photobg {
 background-image:url('photourl.jpg');
}

#gradientbg {
 background-image:url('1pxgradient.jpg');
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 background-position: 1780px 0;
 height: 100%;
}
```

What I'd like to do, in theory, is use color stops at 1780 px for a CSS gradient but as I understand it, CSS only supports % values as color stops.

Reference: 
[CSS 3 Gradient n pixels from bottom - Webkit/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707828/css-3-gradient-n-pixels-from-bottom-webkit-safari)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can use pixels with linear gradient:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 1780px, black 100%);
```

You can also combine this gradient with multiple background images on one `div`.

You might want to check out this jsbin, I've made for you:
http://jsbin.com/sonewa/1/edit

Comment: Oops, I just saw right now, that this question is already more than two years old. 8[

Answer (score -1):

This block of css will do what you want

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #00AFF0, #53D4FE); //this is for mozilla
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00AFF0, #53D4FE); //this is for chrome and safari
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00AFF0', endColorstr='#53D4FE', GradientType=0); //this is for IE
```

while the gradient is from color #00AFF0 to #53D4FE (top to bottom)

Comment: I'm not looking for a gradient example for Webkit- I am looking for a solution to beginning a gradient at a pixel location rather than a % of the background. This is not the answer.